# Can I listen to event hub from app service environment without service endpoint?

Tags: azure-eventhub, app-service-environment

Basically can I have Azure Function or web job with App Service environment listening to event hub without service endpoint. This way I will be able to accept data over public internet and also listen to in vnet?

Adding probable Security architecture:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Service Endpoints saves your time by doing IP firewall and NAT and gateway configuration changes in your VNET. If you will do those changes on your own, then yes you can access any public endpoint from your VNET.

Comment: But Service Endpoint would also limit sending data to event hub from anywhere apart form Vnet. Is this understanding correct?

Comment: Service Endpoint configures VNET to reach public service endpoint with the private IP plus w/o leaving Azure backbone network. VNET configuration on the EH namespace actually ensures your namespace won't accept any traffic outside of subject VNET.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But if i want to expose my event hub publicly so that it accepts data from everywhere, but want processing, storage and APIs in vnet then what is the appropriate option? I can't have static ip for event hub.

Comment: I am a little confused. Event Hubs accepts public traffic by default. If you are not constraining outgoing traffic in your VNET, any VNET resource can access to your namespace as well. Can you elaborate a little more about how the VNET topology will look like?

Comment: I've added topology in my question. Could you please check? Event Hubs accept public traffic by default, but if we add service endpoint, it will not be accept the public traffic. And if my processing logic is in VNET, can i directly listen to event hub without any configuration or service endpoint in VNET?

Comment: Enabling Service Endpoint on the VNET doesn't make any configurational changes for your Event Hubs namespace. In other words, any app in your VNET can access Event Hubs namespace via either private IP when SE enabled or the public IP when SE isn't enabled. Your VNET architecture looks good in that sense and it should work just fine.